# How to type a tree of nested ES6 Maps with Typescript

Tags: typescript

With regular JS objects, I can type a tree (with nulls as leafs) like this:

```
interface Tree {
  [key: string]: Tree | null;
}
```

How to type a structure that is similar, except it uses ES6 Maps instead of objects (I would need this for example when keys can be something other than strings)? In other words, how to get around the problem that circular references are only possible with interfaces, not aliases, and you can't have

```
type Tree = Map<string, Tree | null>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an alias, you could maybe create a class that represent this type of object as

```
class Tree extends Map<string, Tree | null> {}
```

What do you think about this approach ?

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Yes, this looks like it should work! Thanks, I'll try this in my code.